# Table (or similar) of numbered displayed math

Tags: tables, equations, arrays

I want to refer to a "table" of equations, but I want every "cell" to be numbered. All answers I have seen of anything similar deal with numbering lines, but I'd like to number individual cells as well. Here's the minimal code:

```
\begin{align*}
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
p & q & p\wedge q\\\hline
1 & 1 & 1\\\hline
1 & 0 & 0\\\hline
0 & 1 & 0\\\hline
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array} &&&
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
p & q & p\vee q\\\hline
1 & 1 & 1\\\hline
1 & 0 & 1\\\hline
0 & 1 & 1\\\hline
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}\\[1.3ex]
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
p & q & p\veebar q\\\hline
1 & 1 & 0\\\hline
1 & 0 & 1\\\hline
0 & 1 & 1\\\hline
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}&&&
\begin{array}{c|c}
p & \neg p\\\hline
1 & 0 \\\hline
0 & 1\\
\end{array}
\end{align*}
```

A screencap of the output is below; what I want is for every truth table to have its own tag (not necessesarily a number, just to be able to use `\tag` on each one) so I can later refer to them.

[image]

Comment: Like that? https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhotI.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution with `tabularx`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
Some text. Some more text.

{\centering \renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}XX@{}}
\begin{equation}\label{TT:AND}
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
p & q & p\wedge q\\\hline
1 & 1 & 1\\\hline
1 & 0 & 0\\\hline
0 & 1 & 0\\\hline
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\end{equation} &
\begin{equation}\label{TT:OR}
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
p & q & p\vee q\\\hline
1 & 1 & 1\\\hline
1 & 0 & 1\\\hline
0 & 1 & 1\\\hline
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\end{equation} \\[-2ex]
%
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{c|c|c}\label{TT:XOR}
p & q & p\veebar q\\\hline
1 & 1 & 0\\\hline
1 & 0 & 1\\\hline
0 & 1 & 1\\\hline
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\end{equation}&
\begin{equation}\label{TT:NEG}
\begin{array}{c|c}
p & \neg p\\\hline
1 & 0 \\\hline
0 & 1
\end{array}
\end{equation}
\end{tabularx}\vskip -1ex
}

Text continuation.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't know about this package. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution that (a) places each `array` environment in an `equation` environment, (b) places each `equation` environment in a `minipage` environment of width `0.5\linewidth`, and (c) places the four `minipage` environments in a `center` environment. Embedding the `minipage` environments in a `center` environment assures that there will be bit of whitespace above and below the group of four arrays.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}    % for '\extrarowheight' macro
\usepackage{amssymb}  % for '\veebar' macro
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\setlength\extrarowheight{1pt} % for a less "cramped" look

\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}\begin{equation}\begin{array}{c|c|c}
p & q & p\wedge q \\ \hline
1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
1 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
0 & 1 & 0 \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\end{equation}\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}\begin{equation}\begin{array}{c|c|c}
p & q & p\vee q \\ \hline
1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
1 & 0 & 1 \\ \hline
0 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\end{equation}\end{minipage}

\vspace{5mm} % or whatever amount of vertical spacing you prefer
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}\begin{equation}\begin{array}{c|c|c}
p & q & p\veebar q \\ \hline
1 & 1 & 0 \\ \hline
1 & 0 & 1 \\ \hline
0 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 0 
\end{array}\end{equation}\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}\begin{equation}\begin{array}{c|c}
p & \neg p \\ \hline
1 & 0 \\   \hline
0 & 1 \\
\end{array}\end{equation}\end{minipage}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It was so obvious. Thanks!!! ;)